# integration over non specified circle with centre inside specified circle

Tags: calculus

$f(x,y)$ is a continious function over the unity circle $D = x^2 + y^2 <1$

$B_r (a,b)$ is a circle in the plane with its centre at (a,b) and radius $r$.

How can I show the following statement is true for all $(a,b) \in D$?

$\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{r^2} \iint_{B_r (a,b)} f(x,y) dx dy = \pi f(a,b)$

Comment: Is $f$ defined outside of $D$? If not, I don’t see how you can say anything about that limit when $(a,b)$ is an arbitrary point on the plane.

Comment: @amd $f(x,y)$ is only defined on the unity disc with the radius 1, and we also know that the point (a,b) is somewhere on this unity disc. Is it maybe possible to use the mean value theorem for definite integrals in some way since we got f both inside and outside of the integral?